# Get device token in static library

Tags: ios, ios7, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

I have to get device Token from Apple Push Notification Server in static library.

That means user do not have to implement didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken method in AppDelegate, i have to handle it my self, and get device token.

- Does it possible to get device token else where in program ?
- Is there any method that will notify me when device token is generated ?

Because i have to register device token after user logged-in. So I have implemented my code such that

1. didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken i am calling static library method to save device token ( That will save device token in NSUSerDefault )
2. After user logged-in i am sending device token to Server for adding that device token in Database.

I do not have to save device Token and then register, i have to generate device token one time when user log in and send it to server.

So, Does it possible ?

Thanks & Regards,
Abbas Mulani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is the only way to get the device token from Apple after registering for push notifications (by calling `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:`). This method can pass the device token to where ever you need it, or store it in some persistent store (such as `NSUSerDefault`), so that it can be accessed by who ever needs it.

If you want to get the device token form Apple only when the user logs in, you should call `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` only when the user logs in.